# Detect USB Samsung NX3000 camera

Tags: usb, samsung, camera, mtp, lsusb

My samsung NX3000 camera isnt detected on Ubuntu 20.10.
When cable is ON, the camera enters "USB connection" mode, but nothing happens on Ubuntu.

- it doesnt appear in nautilus (neither main menu neither Network page)
- gphoto2 doesnt see it
- lsusb doesnt list it :

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5a7 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Chicony USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can i recover access to its photographs ?

Comment: I don't know the answer. However, the NX3000 has slow USB 2.0 only. Would be better anyways to have a microsd -> USB 3.0 adapter and copy files directly from the card. You can get those for less than 10€ / $.

Comment: OK i ordered an adapter @pLumo... I'm surprised there is no answer yet. I have never had issues connecting other cameras or phones in the past, except this camera. Samsung is not supposed to propose awkward or uncommon technologies.

Comment: The adapter works ok. I have to not loose it now coz these things are pretty small. That's a disadvantage compared to installed software.